# Declare C++ primitive type member whose address cannot be known?

Tags: c++, member, memory-address

I'd like to declare a primitive type member in a class that forbids usage of operator&().  In other words: I don't want anyone to ever take the address of this member (and possibly pass it to other classes or functions, etc.)

Is this possible without using a wrapper type?

Comment: So given a class `C` with `int` member `m`, you want to stop someone from doing this : `C c; int *p = &c.m;` but not stop them from doing this: `C c; C* p = &c;`. Is that correct ?

Comment: You're a terrible person.  You know that, right?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley who me ? (and yes, I know that regardless).

Comment: @WhozCraig: No. The OP, for wanting to do this.

Comment: This has all the feeling of a "XY problem"

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I want to prevent &m or &c.m in any context whatsoever.  The address of C can be known.

Comment: declare `m` as private is not enough ?

Comment: So why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `operator&()` as private which prevent the address being taken with the `&` prefix, but `std::addressof` can always be used to circumvent that. Taking the address cannot be prevented, but it can be made for difficult as a deterrent.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your class is A

Put this in your class declaration

```
A* operator&() = delete;
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your member as private, and your getter doesn't return reference/pointer.
it works also for non primitive-class (with the cost of the copy)

```
class A
{
public:
   const A* operator & () const = delete; // pre-require of OP
   A* operator&() = delete;               // pre-require of OP.

   int getMember() const { return member; }
   void setMember(int value) { member = value;} 

   // Other stuff.

private:
    int member;
};
```